# The set of isolated points is open?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, let $A \subseteq X$ be a subset such that every $a \in A$ is an isolated point of $X$. Then A is an open subset of $X$ ?

Is this statement true or false?

I know that if $A$ is finite, then $A$ should be open, but what if $A$ is infinite? Can someone give me a proof or counterexample? Thanks!

Comment: Obviously false, even if $A$ is finite. Take $\mathbb{R}$ with usual metric and $A = \{0\}$. With all due respect, you should take some time to update your intuition on these notions.

Comment: Have you considered any examples...? (Perhaps take $(X, d)$ to be the real line with the usual metric.)

Comment: @mathworker21 Why 0 is an isolated point on $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: @ZHANGYUE Obviously $0$ is not an isolated point of $\mathbb{R}$, but $0$ is an isolated point of the set $A = \{ 0\}$. Maybe you should review the definition of an isolated point and read about some examples?

Comment: Probably the set $A$ consists of points of $X$ which are isolated in $X$... The way you wrote this question @ZHANGYUE, does not make this clear at all.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Sorry, it should be isolated point of $X$... just edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the edit. Note that by your hypothesis $\{a \}$ is an open set of $X$ for all $a \in A$. And we have $A = \bigcup_{a \in A} \{a\}$, so $A$ is open.